# Color mismatch between legend and scatter plot elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am unable to use the same colors in legend as coming from my cycled data. '*alldata*' has a size 569x30 so defining that many colors is not feasible

```
for labels in ['benign', 'malignant']:
       scatter = plt.scatter(svd_pca_eqvt[:,0],svd_pca_eqvt[:,1],label=labels, c=alldata['target'])
plt.legend()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFPdo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the colors in the for loop instead like the following:

```
for labels, color in zip (['benign', 'malignant'], ['#FECB52','#7E1E9C']):
       scatter = plt.scatter(svd_pca_eqvt[:,0],svd_pca_eqvt[:,1],label=labels, c=color)
plt.legend()
```

#FECB52 --> yellow
#7E1E9C --> Dark Purple